# Automatic Address Fill In Form Using Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to use Geolocation to automatically fill in the address fields for my users. Where I am struggling is on (Mailing Address 1:) & (Physical Address 1:) As of now it will show the user addresses once they start typing but when they select and make their choice for their address I do not want the entire address plus city state and zipcode on `Mailing Address 1:`. I want it show Street Number and Street Address then fill in the other fields (city, state, zip) leaving `Mailing Address 2:` blank in case they have an apartment or suite.

Then if you select that the physical and mailing addresses are the same obviously I would like it to fill in exactly like above.

If the addresses are not the same I would like it to follow the same process as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  }
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    

  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="m2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="m2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route" size="54" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
      
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing state." value="">
    </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
    </div>
      </div>

          <div class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" id="chbSame" />
  <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>
 
        

          <div id="locationField2">
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstreet_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete2" size="53" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical address." onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">
    </div> 

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="p2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="p2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route2" size="53" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
            
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pcity_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pcity_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality2" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical city." value="">
      </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical state." value="">
    </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="ppostal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code2" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical zip code." value="">
    </div>​​
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

works fine for me.

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="m2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="m2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route" size="54" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
      
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing state." value="">
    </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
    </div>
      </div>

          <div class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" id="chbSame" />
  <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>
 
        

          <div id="locationField2">
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstreet_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete2" size="53" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical address." onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">
    </div> 

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="p2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="p2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route2" size="53" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
            
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pcity_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pcity_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality2" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical city." value="">
      </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical state." value="">
    </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="ppostal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code2" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical zip code." value="">
    </div>​​
            </div>
```

EDIT:  updated as per comments below

EDIT 2: As per comments below

EDIT 3: As per another comments below :)

EDIT 4: As per yet another comments below :)

EDIT 5: -||-

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I don't follow what is meant by this sentence: "I have to have it where it does that calculation from Mailing address one". I think this demo can be adjusted easily. I'm just not sure what is desired behavior.

Comment: I tried your example but it doesn't fill the sub-fields (city,postal,address). Not sure if I follow - you'd like to fill the sub-fields and clear the autocomplete textbox itself? J

Comment: OK, so you start typing on the autocomplete textbox to look up some location. Choose for example "New York, Brooklyn, 12st street" and pick it up. Then, the sub-fields should be filled up (City=New York, State=NY and so on..) and the original autocomplete field should then contain only the street name? So in this case "12st street" ?

Comment: Ivan, can you explain what you did to help Alex solve his problem? Your answer just says "Try this, works for me", but doesn't explain what you did in order to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: @radiovisual sure. it's all in the comments history.

Comment: @DavidBrierton go ahead :)

Comment: @DavidBrierton sorry David, not following.. .valid()? Don't know what this func does.

Comment: @IvanSivak the issue is that when it prefills the other textboxes the other textboxes are not aware for validation. so they can be filled but unless u click in there box my red css does not disappear unless it knows there is something in it which is why we use the .valid()

Comment: kind of like this: `$(document).on('change blur keyup mouseup ', function() {
  var test = $('#locality').val();
  console.log(test);
     if ($('#locality').val() !== '') {
         $('#locality').valid();
     }
  if ($('#administrative_area_level_1').val() !== '') {
         $('#administrative_area_level_1').valid();
     }
  if ($('#postal_code').val() !== '') {
         $('#postal_code').valid();
     }`

Comment: @DavidBrierton OK, just looking at the code and can't see the valid() functione anywhere.

Comment: its ok I was misunderstanding what .valid() does sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="m2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="m2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route" size="54" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
      
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing state." value="">
    </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
    </div>
      </div>

          <div class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" id="chbSame" />
  <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>
 
        

          <div id="locationField2">
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstreet_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete2" size="53" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical address." onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">
    </div> 

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="p2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="p2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route2" size="53" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
            
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pcity_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pcity_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality2" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical city." value="">
      </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical state." value="">
    </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="ppostal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code2" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical zip code." value="">
    </div>​​
            </div>
```

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="m2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="m2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route" size="54" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
      
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing state." value="">
    </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
    </div>
      </div>

          <div class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" id="chbSame" />
  <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>
 
        

          <div id="locationField2">
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstreet_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete2" size="53" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical address." onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">
    </div> 

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="p2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="p2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route2" size="53" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
            
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pcity_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pcity_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality2" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical city." value="">
      </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical state." value="">
    </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="ppostal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code2" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical zip code." value="">
    </div>​​
            </div>
```

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="m2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Mailing Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="m2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route" size="54" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
      
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing state." value="">
    </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
    </div>
      </div>

          <div class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>" id="chbSame" />
  <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>
 
        

          <div id="locationField2">
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstreet_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete2" size="53" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical address." onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">
    </div> 

    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="p2street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Physical Address 2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="p2street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" required="no" validate="maxlength" id="route2" size="53" maxlength="120" value="">
    </div>
            
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pcity_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">City:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pcity_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality2" size="30" maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical city." value="">
      </div>
            
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_#Add#" required="yes" id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical state." value="">
    </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstreet_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" name="ppostal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code2" size="8" maxlength="12" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s physical zip code." value="">
    </div>​​
            </div>
```

Comment: When i run this code it is running but when i use this code it does`t work can you help sir . and first text box show always the message 'some thing went worng'

Comment: Try posting it as another question rather than posting it as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask